# Should you start a new paragraph for a new speaker if both speakers are contained in the same quoted passage?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, dialogue

This manuscript quotes a passage from the Bible that has more than one speaker:

Job 1:6–7 says:

> One day, when the angels had gathered around the Lord, and Satan was there with them, the Lord asked, "Satan, where have you been?" Satan replied, "I have been going all over the earth."

Normally, whenever a new speaker is introduced in dialogue, it starts a new paragraph. But does that rule apply when those speakers are contained within the same quotation?

Comment: I edited your question to use a block quote. The use of embedded quotation marks was making it difficult to understand what was going on. As for the question, no. There is no *rule* that you must use a separate paragraph for different speakers. So long as who is talking is made clear, there is no reason that you have to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should you always start a new paragraph when starting a new speaker even if the sentence directly before that is directly related?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62536/should-you-always-start-a-new-paragraph-when-starting-a-new-speaker-even-if-the)

Comment: The [MLA style guide](https://style.mla.org/quotations-and-paragraph-breaks/) suggests you don't have to preserve paragraphing when quoting text, so you can insert or remove breaks. Although some style guides may differ.

Answer (score 1):

What you call the *rule* is more of a convention, and can be subject to common sense.  In general, if you are narrating a dialogue in a novel or short story, it makes it easier for the reader to follow what is going on.  But there can be contexts in which that convention is unnecessary and may, in some contexts, be distracting.

In this case, you are quoting from the Old Testament, which is written in verses, which are preserved in the English rendition of the original Hebrew.  You would find exactly the same with manuscripts of, say, Homer's *Iliad* or *Odyssey*.  These are written in hexameter verse without paragraphs of any kind.  But the same is true of John Milton's *Paradise Lost*.

Comment: Note that the translation quoted is apparently a "modern" one (apparently CEV) that may not adhere to the format of the original Hebrew.

Comment: @HotLicks You have a point.  The Modern International  version of Abraham’s debate with God over the fate of Abraham is inconsistant in its layout, https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.biblegateway.com/passage/%3Fsearch%3DGenesis%252018%253A16-33%26version%3DNIV%26interface%3Damp but does mainly set out the text in speech paragraphs.